# Aws Pass Value from Lambda Trigger to Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

When using a Lambda Function to trigger a Step Function, how do you get the output of the function that triggered it?

Comment: Do you want to pass said output to the Step Function or somewhere else ?

Comment: To the step function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you want to pass an input to a Step Function execution (or, more exactly, your *'State Machine'*'s execution), you just need to set said input the `input` property when calling `StartExecution` (see [AWS Documentation: Start Execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html))

In your case, it would most likely be your lambda's last step before calling it's callback.

If it's a node js lambda, that's what it would look like

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const stepfunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions();

exports.myHandler = function(event, context, callback) {

    ... your function's code

    const params = {
       stateMachineArn: 'YOUR_STATE_MACHINE_ARN', /* required */
       input: 'STRINGIFIED INPUT',
       name: 'AN EXECUTION NAME (such as an uuid or whatever)'
    };
    stepfunctions.startExecution(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) callback(err); // an error occurred
       else     callback(null, "some success message"); // successful response
    });

}
```

Alternatively, if your payload is too big, you could store the data in S3 or DynamoDB and pass the reference to it as your State Machine's execution's input.